# Absolute path to Relative Path in Unix

Tags: unix, ls

This command was to list only the text files in my fileAsst directory:

```
  ls ~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/*.txt
```

now I need to do the same thing but using a relative path instead, what I've tried so far is:

```
  ls ~/UnixCourse/../*.txt
```

but it's saying I'm not getting the right answer, can anyone give me some hints or explain the differences between a relative path and absolute path, because I still dont under it.

Comment: `~/UnixCourse/../.txt` is the same as going `~/.txt`. The `../` is saying "go back one folder" basically.

Comment: In relatove path it specifies ../ as upward hierarchy in the path ,

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Path:
The absolute path is a path that contains the root directory and all other sub directories that contain a file or folder.

```
  ~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/*.txt
```

Relative path:
The  relative path is only a portion of the full path.

```
  cd ~UnixCourse/fileAsst/ 

  ls *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative is always, well, relative to some existing directory, you are currently "located" in (by means of the `cd` command, usually). In your question you don't show what the current directory is. So there is no single "correct" answer.

If your current directory is, say, `~` (which is just a shortcut for your home directory, for example, `/home/myuser`), then you're relative `ls` command would look like (I'm adding the implied previous `cd` command for clarity):

```
 cd ~
 ls UnixCourse/fileAsst/*.txt
```

likewise if your current directory is `~/UnixCourse`, then your relative `ls` command would look like:

```
 cd ~/UnixCourse
 ls fileAsst/*.txt
```

or the most simply case, when you are already in the directory you want to list the contents of:

```
 cd ~/UnixCourse/fileAsst
 ls *.txt
```

Get the idea?

Finally, as you have (accidentally, I'd assume) discovered, you can use `..` and `.` in your paths, to imply "one (sub)directory up" or "the current directory".

For example, the following paths are equivalent and all resolve to "UnixCourse/fileAsst":

```
 UnixCourse/../UnixCourse/fileAsst/
 UnixCourse/SomeOtherDir/../fileAsst/
 UnixCourse/./fileAsst
 UnixCourse/fileAsst/YetAnotherDir/../
```

Note that this is a orthogonal concept and can be used with both, relative and absolute, paths.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes of pathname:

1. Absolute: start with a slash.
2. Relative: don't start with a slash.

Absolute pathnames have the same meaning regardless of your current working directory.  An absolute pathname might contain `..` components after the initial slash.  An absolute pathname with no `..` components that traverses no symlinks is sometimes known as a 'real path', after the system call `realpath()` that can be used to determine the real path of a name.

Relative pathnames are relative to the current working directory; conceptually, every relative pathname could be deemed to start with `./`.  A relative name might start with `..` to move upwards from the current working directory.  A special case of relative pathname is a simple filename — a name with no explicit directory component.  That is a file (or other named object) in the current directory, of course.

To determine a relative pathname from an absolute pathname, you also have to know the current working directory.

For more information, see:

- [bash — Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory/2565049#2565049)
- [How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path) — tagged [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and applying to Windows rather than Unix.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't see a one-lined answer...

```
ls ../fileAsst/*.txt
```

Hope that can help someone!