# create a minimal symlink

Tags: shell

I'm looking for an (preferably portable) way to create 'short' relative symbolic links. That is for two absolute file names `target` and `name` I want to find an equivalent and short relative file name `reltarget` such that after

```
ln -s $target $name
```

`name` points to the same location as after

```
ln -s $reltarget $name
```

.

Some examples:

```
target="/usr/bin/program-1.2"; name="/usr/bin/program";
=> reltarget="program-1.2"

target="/usr/lib/program-1.2/bin/program"; name="/usr/bin/program-1.2";
=> reltarget="../lib/program-1.2/bin/program"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it if you have Python 2.6 or newer on your system; you may need to modify the quoting if launching from another shell than bash.

```
ln -s "`python -c "import os.path; print os.path.relpath('$target','$name')"`" "$name"
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305217/477878).

Comment: I read the question you linked and the answers there can easily be converted to my question. That's the most nice alternative. Thanks.