# ccache ignores CCACHE_DIR

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, clang, ccache

I have two identical projects with the same file

```
/Users/Steve/Desktop/foo/a.cpp
/Users/Steve/Desktop/bar/a.cpp
```

I use `ccache` to speedup the compilation across directory boundaries, so I defined `CCACHE_BASEDIR`

```
export CCACHE_BASEDIR=/Users/Steve/Desktop/
```

I compile the file with the following command:

```
export CCACHE_NOHASHDIR=true
export CCACHE_BASEDIR=/Users/Steve/Desktop
ccache clang++ -c /Users/Steve/Desktop/foo/a.cpp
ccache clang++ -c /Users/Steve/Desktop/bar/a.cpp
```

Is there any reason why the object file for bar/a.cpp doesn't get pulled from the cache?

Comment: What is `b.cpp` and which folder is it in? How does it relate to the two `a.cpp` files?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It was `a.cpp`

Comment: Why `CCACHE_BASEDIR` in the question, but `CCACHE_DIR` in the title? Also, how are you determining that it's not pulling in the object file from the cache? Does `a.cpp` `#include` files that are next to it? If so, are they also identical?

Comment: In addition to @KenThomases's question, also check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303281/1062948) helps (but you have set `CCACHE_NOHASHDIR`, so that might not be relevant).

Comment: Can you provide an answer to your own question (presuming it was solved)? [Self-answered questions are encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) (but it is a good idea anyway to leave a comment on the answer to explain it (as not all (down-)voters are aware of it). You can use the reference I provided here.).

Comment: I didn’t solve my problem. I fixed my question