# unix how to read relative path directly

Tags: unix

UNIX pwd command is giving below:
    /nfs/site/disks/machine_51/main_dir/

I can go to the same directory by doing
    cd /p/main_dir

Is there a command or way to modify pwd so that when I run that command from main_dir, it gives me relative path (not absolute path) ?

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498485/1525759

Comment: Both of the paths you give `/nfs/site/disks/machine_51/main_dir/` and `/p/main_dir` are *absolute* paths, starting with a `/` — neither is a relative path. Do you mean one is a symbolic link to the other, or one is a mount point?

Comment: Don't actually understand what you're asking. The sole purpose of `pwd` is to display the current working directory in absolute path. If you don't need to know that, you don't need to run the command `pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing below:

1. In .cshrc, added `set symlinks = ignore` (came to know this this tcsh setting)
2. In UNIX prompt, type `cwd` in place of `pwd`