# BASH: Path difference between two paths?

Tags: bash, shell, filepath

Say I have the paths

```
a/b/c/d/e/f
a/b/c/d
```

How do I get the below?

```
e/f
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can strip one string from the other with:

```
echo "${string1#"$string2"}"
```

See:

```
$ string1="a/b/c/d/e/f"
$ string2="a/b/c/d"
$ echo "${string1#"$string2"}"
/e/f
```

From `man bash` -> [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${parameter#word}
>
> ${parameter##word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value
>   of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value
>   of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted.

---

With spaces:

```
$ string1="hello/i am here/foo/bar"
$ string2="hello/i am here/foo"
$ echo "${string1#"$string2"}"
/bar
```

To "clean" multiple slashes, you can follow [Roberto Reale's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725391/bash-path-difference-between-two-paths#comment40219062_25725435) and canonicalize the paths with `readlink -m` to allow comparison with strings with the same real path up:

```
$ string1="/a///b/c//d/e/f/"
$ readlink -m $string1
/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (from this [other related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28523143/7212665)) is:

```
$ realpath -m --relative-to=a/b/c/d a/b/c/d/e/f
e/f
```

It properly handles spaces (quote the path in that case) and multiple slashes.

The option `-m` is simply here to avoid errors when either path doesn't exist.