# Symlinking relative paths without expanding symlinks

Tags: c, linux, symlink

Working in C on linux, I have two character arrays containing paths relative to the cwd. Let's say they're `"foo/txt"` and `"bar/txt"`. I want to create a symlink that points from the first to the second. Problem is if I go `symlink("bar/txt", "foo/txt")`, `foo/txt` will look for `foo/bar/txt` which doesn't exist. I could add `".."` to the beginning of the target path but I don't know how many directory levels are contained in the source string

Compounding the issue is that the target my itself be a symlink and I do not want to traverse it, as might happen if I used `realpath()`. The directory structure might look like the following, once links are created as I intend (for my purposes it doesn't matter if the resulting symlinks are relative or absolute):

```
/somecwd/foo/txt -> ../bar/txt
/somecwd/bar/txt -> ../baz/txt
/somecww/baz/txt
```

Does anyone know how I might go about this? Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Ideally this would work even if the paths that I'm given are absolute instead

Answer (score 1):

With the `symlink()` function, the BSD (Mac OS X) man page says:

> ```
>  int symlink(const char *path1, const char *path2);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> A symbolic link `path2` is created to `path1` (`path2` is the name of the file created, `path1` is the string used in creating the symbolic link).  Either name may be an arbitrary path name; the files need not be on the same file system.

Note that what you specify as `path1` is used, verbatim, as the content of the symlink.  Thus, to make the symlink accurately, you have to get the relative path correct.  That is, the name passed as `path1` must be the correct name relative to `path2`.

In other words, you can't completely avoid the process of mapping the names, with all the attendant difficulties.

I have a Perl script, `relpath`, that I cobbled together from the answer to [Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634) and a fairly old news group message from [comp.unix.shell](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2005-10/1256.html).  Converting some of this to C is not beyond the wit of mankind.  In fact, it is bound to have been done numerous times.  The difficulty will be finding the code.

#### relpath

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: relpath.pl,v 1.4 2014/12/08 18:23:17 jleffler Exp $
#
# Usage:    relpath source target [...]
#
# Purpose:  Print relative path of target w.r.t. source
#
# Based loosely on code from:
# http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2005-10/1256.html
# Via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Cwd qw(realpath getcwd);

if (scalar @ARGV < 2)
{
    my $arg0 = basename($0, ".pl");
    die "Usage: $arg0 from to [...]\n"
}

my $pwd;
my $verbose = 0;

# Fettle filename so it is absolute.
# Deals with '//', '/./' and '/../' notations, plus symlinks.
# The realpath() function does the hard work if the path exists.
# For non-existent paths, the code does a purely textual hack.
sub resolve
{
    my($name) = @_;
    my($path) = realpath($name);
    if (!defined $path)
    {
        # Path does not exist - do the best we can with lexical analysis
        # Assume Unix - not dealing with Windows.
        $path = $name;
        if ($name !~ m%^/%)
        {
            $pwd = getcwd if !defined $pwd;
            $path = "$pwd/$path";
        }
        $path =~ s%//+%/%g;     # Not UNC paths.
        $path =~ s%/$%%;        # No trailing /
        $path =~ s%/\./%/%g;    # No embedded /./
        # Try to eliminate /../abc/
        $path =~ s%/\.\./(?:[^/]+)(/|$)%$1%g;
        $path =~ s%/\.$%%;      # No trailing /.
        $path =~ s%^\./%%;      # No leading ./
        # What happens with . and / as inputs?
    }
    return($path);
}

sub print_result
{
    my($source, $target, $relpath) = @_;
    if ($verbose)
    {
        print "source  = $ARGV[0]\n";
        print "target  = $ARGV[1]\n";
        print "relpath = $relpath\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "$relpath\n";
    }
}

# Nasty!
my($source) = resolve($ARGV[0]);
my(@source) = split '/', $source;
shift @ARGV;

sub relpath
{
    my($name) = @_;
    my($target) = resolve($name);
    print_result($source, $target, ".") if ($source eq $target);

    # Split!
    my(@target) = split '/', $target;

    my $count = scalar(@source);
       $count = scalar(@target) if (scalar(@target) < $count);
    my $relpath = "";
    my $i;

    # Both paths are absolute; Perl splits an empty field 0.
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        last if $source[$i] ne $target[$i];
    }

    for (my $s = $i; $s < scalar(@source); $s++)
    {
        $relpath = "$relpath/" if ($s > $i);
        $relpath = "$relpath..";
    }
    for (my $t = $i; $t < scalar(@target); $t++)
    {
        $relpath = "$relpath/" if ($relpath ne "");
        $relpath = "$relpath$target[$t]";
    }

    print_result($source, $target, $relpath);
}

foreach my $target (@ARGV)
{
    relpath($target);
}
```

#### test.relpath

NB: This requires `relpath.pl` rather than just `relpath`.

```sh
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id: test.relpath.sh,v 1.1 2010/04/25 15:19:20 jleffler Exp $
#
# Test relpath Perl script fairly exhaustively
# BUG: should include expected answers!

sed 's/#.*//;/^[    ]*$/d' <<! |

/home/part1/part2 /home/part1/part3
/home/part1/part2 /home/part4/part5
/home/part1/part2 /work/part6/part7
/home/part1       /work/part1/part2/part3/part4
/home             /work/part2/part3
/                 /work/part2/part3/part4

/home/part1/part2 /home/part1/part2/part3/part4
/home/part1/part2 /home/part1/part2/part3
/home/part1/part2 /home/part1/part2
/home/part1/part2 /home/part1
/home/part1/part2 /home
/home/part1/part2 /

/home/part1/part2 /work
/home/part1/part2 /work/part1
/home/part1/part2 /work/part1/part2
/home/part1/part2 /work/part1/part2/part3
/home/part1/part2 /work/part1/part2/part3/part4

home/part1/part2 home/part1/part3
home/part1/part2 home/part4/part5
home/part1/part2 work/part6/part7
home/part1       work/part1/part2/part3/part4
home             work/part2/part3
.                work/part2/part3

home/part1/part2 home/part1/part2/part3/part4
home/part1/part2 home/part1/part2/part3
home/part1/part2 home/part1/part2
home/part1/part2 home/part1
home/part1/part2 home
home/part1/part2 .

home/part1/part2 work
home/part1/part2 work/part1
home/part1/part2 work/part1/part2
home/part1/part2 work/part1/part2/part3
home/part1/part2 work/part1/part2/part3/part4

!

{
echo "Relative paths (source, target, relative path)"
while read source target
do
    echo "$source $target $(${PERL:-perl} relpath.pl $source $target)"
done |
awk '{ printf("%-20s   %-30s   %s\n", $1, $2, $3); }'
}
```

#### Example output

Note that the first relative path, `../part3`, is correct if `/home/part1/part2` is a directory, or is assumed to be a directory.  This code requires care in interpreting the output.  Note that the `symlink()` system call does not require that the `path1` name refers to an existing file or directory (but, by contrast, `path2` must not refer to an existing file or directory, though only the leaf element must not exist; all previous directories must exist).

```
Relative paths (source, target, relative path)
/home/part1/part2      /home/part1/part3                ../part3
/home/part1/part2      /home/part4/part5                ../../part4/part5
/home/part1/part2      /work/part6/part7                ../../../work/part6/part7
/home/part1            /work/part1/part2/part3/part4    ../../work/part1/part2/part3/part4
/home                  /work/part2/part3                ../work/part2/part3
/                      /work/part2/part3/part4          work/part2/part3/part4
/home/part1/part2      /home/part1/part2/part3/part4    part3/part4
/home/part1/part2      /home/part1/part2/part3          part3
/home/part1/part2      /home/part1/part2                .
/home/part1/part2      /home/part1                      ..
/home/part1/part2      /home                            ../..
/home/part1/part2      /                                ../../..
/home/part1/part2      /work                            ../../../work
/home/part1/part2      /work/part1                      ../../../work/part1
/home/part1/part2      /work/part1/part2                ../../../work/part1/part2
/home/part1/part2      /work/part1/part2/part3          ../../../work/part1/part2/part3
/home/part1/part2      /work/part1/part2/part3/part4    ../../../work/part1/part2/part3/part4
home/part1/part2       home/part1/part3                 ../part3
home/part1/part2       home/part4/part5                 ../../part4/part5
home/part1/part2       work/part6/part7                 ../../../work/part6/part7
home/part1             work/part1/part2/part3/part4     ../../work/part1/part2/part3/part4
home                   work/part2/part3                 ../work/part2/part3
.                      work/part2/part3                 work/part2/part3
home/part1/part2       home/part1/part2/part3/part4     part3/part4
home/part1/part2       home/part1/part2/part3           part3
home/part1/part2       home/part1/part2                 .
home/part1/part2       home/part1                       ..
home/part1/part2       home                             ../..
home/part1/part2       .                                ../../..
home/part1/part2       work                             ../../../work
home/part1/part2       work/part1                       ../../../work/part1
home/part1/part2       work/part1/part2                 ../../../work/part1/part2
home/part1/part2       work/part1/part2/part3           ../../../work/part1/part2/part3
home/part1/part2       work/part1/part2/part3/part4     ../../../work/part1/part2/part3/part4
```

Answer (score 0):

As a fast solution (ignoring double slashes, `../` and `./`), you can count the number of slashes in the source and prepend the same number of `../`.