# Find absolute path of a directory *relative* to the current directory

Tags: linux, pwd

`pwd` gives the absolute path to the current directory. **Is there a way to give the absolute path of a directory *relative* to the current directory?** (It's admittedly an almost non-problem.)

Normal pwd:

```
[/x/y/z]$ pwd
/x/y/z
```

Relative could be like:

```
[/x/y/z]$ pwd ../a/b 
/x/y/a/b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory using Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory-using-bash)

Comment: @Thrustmaster It's not. There absolute path is given and you need to convert it to relative

Comment: Michael you are using absolute path

Comment: Question should be phrased differently.

Comment: Apologies, I understood the question wrongly. How about: `(cd ../a/b; pwd)`

Answer (score 3):

You want absolute according to your question of a directory. Use realpath command:

```
realpath ../a/b
```

Will output absolute path./x/y/a/b

Relative path is what you are giving. ../a/b