# Make Kernel module makefile recognize absolute path for source?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel-module

I'm writing kernel modules to do unit test for a project.
Due to I need to include source files inside the project, I expect to use **absolute path** to those files.
Which would make my Makefile like this

```
foo-objs := dir1/src1.o dir1/src2.o
foo-objs += dir2/src3.o src4.o
foo-objs := $(addprefix $(PROJECT_ROOT),$(foo-objs))
...
all:
$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/"$(shell uname -r)"/build M=$(PWD)
```

**$(PROJECT_ROOT)** would be a environment variable recording **absolute path of the project root**.

By this way, I believe is much clearer and easier to maintain many unit tests.

But when I do `make`, kernel Makefile try to compile $(PWD)/$(PROJECT_ROOT)/src1.o, which of course does not exist. It seems to **treat all object file as relative path**.

As a result, I wonder that if there is a way to **make kernel Makefile for modules to recognize absolute path**, thanks a lot.

Comment: Be familiar with `readlink`, `realpath`, and predefined kernel variables for use in *Makefile*s, i.e. `$(srctree)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know no way to make kernel's Makefiles to recognize absolute paths.

In my projects I have converted absolute paths into relative ones. This conversion is simple with CMake, but I am unsure how to do this in plain Make. You may try to use shell for such purpose, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory-using-bash).

Comment: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Misc/how_kernel_compiled.html Read a paragraph how `$(srctree)` is set.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `srctree` refers to **kernel source tree**. How is it related with paths to **module** sources?

Comment: I think `realpath --relative-to=dir1 dir2` is what I want.
Thanks~.