# SonarQube code coverage report being generated with absolute path

Tags: ios, swift, bash, sonarqube, code-coverage

I generated the SonarQube generic code coverage with the following [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/master/swift-coverage/swift-coverage-example/xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

function convert_file {
  local xccovarchive_file="$1"
  local file_name="$2"
  local xccov_options="$3"
  echo "  <file path=\"$file_name\">"
  xcrun xccov view $xccov_options --file "$file_name" "$xccovarchive_file" | \
    sed -n '
    s/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\): 0.*$/    <lineToCover lineNumber="\1" covered="false"\/>/p;
    s/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\): [1-9].*$/    <lineToCover lineNumber="\1" covered="true"\/>/p
    '
  echo '  </file>'
}

function xccov_to_generic {
  echo '<coverage version="1">'
  for xccovarchive_file in "$@"; do
    local xccov_options=""
    if [[ $xccovarchive_file == *".xcresult"* ]]; then
      xccov_options="--archive"
    fi
    xcrun xccov view $xccov_options --file-list "$xccovarchive_file" | while read -r file_name; do
      convert_file "$xccovarchive_file" "$file_name" "$xccov_options"
    done
  done
  echo '</coverage>'
}

xccov_to_generic "$@"
```

The report is being generated successfully but the file paths are absolute

What's being generated:
`/Users/daniyal/MyApp/AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift`

What I want
`AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift`

Excerpt from sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml currently being generated

```
<coverage version="1">
  <file path="/Users/daniyal/MyApp/AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift">
    <lineToCover lineNumber="27" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="28" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="29" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="30" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="31" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="33" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="34" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="35" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="38" covered="true"/>
    <lineToCover lineNumber="39" covered="true"/>
  </file>
</coverage>
```

Comment: It's not really clear how your parameter $2 to the function convert_file varies to give a clear answer. In any case I would alter the file name on line 8 directly or introduce a new local var in this function to do calculate the file name/ path as you wish.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the script ? change the function `convert_file()` as required?

Answer (score 2):

> What's being generated: `/Users/daniyal/MyApp/AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift`
>
> What I want `AccountStore/AccountStore/AccountProvider.swift`

To trim a prefix from a variable use the [`#` expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```sh
$ echo "$PWD" # PWD is set by the shell
/home/me

$ my_absolute_path=/home/me/some/file.txt

$ echo "Relative path: ${my_absolute_path#${PWD}/}"
Relative path: some/file.txt
```

This trims `${PWD}/` from the start of `${my_absolute_path}`, what's left over is the file's path relative to the current working directory.

So in your case, try:

```
echo "  <file path=\"${file_name#${PWD}/}\">"
```

For more advanced relative-path handling I'd recommend [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31236568/113632), but if you're starting with an absolute path the above is all you need.

---

Consider also using `printf` to output formatted text; something like this will be more readable and likely easier to work with than escaping quotes and `echo`-ing:

```
printf '  <file path="%s">\n' "${file_name#${PWD}/}"
```

Answer (score -1):

In that [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/master/swift-coverage/swift-coverage-example/xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh)

Change this line from:

```
  convert_file "$xccovarchive_file" "$file_name" "$xccov_options"
```

to the following:

```
 convert_file "$xccovarchive_file" "$(echo ${file_name} | cut -d'/' -f5-)" "$xccov_options"
```

You can tweak the number from `5` to something else you want.

**Alternative approach:**

You can pass: `"AccountStore${file_name#*AccountStore}"`

--or--
You can change line: `local file_name="$2"` like `local file_name="AccountStore${2#*AccountStore}"`